# Avoid Writing Duplicates Code using Override annotations

Tags: java, overriding

Below is the class somebody else wrote in our company.

```
public class Reader1 extends PdsxAdapterBaseGemsReader {

    @Override
    public PdsxReader acquireReader(PdsxReadRequest pdsxReadRequest) {
       return new PdsxUserReadOnlyGemsReader(pdsxReadRequest);
    }

    protected static class PdsxUserReadOnlyGemsReader extends PdsxAdapterBaseGemsReader.PdsxBaseGemsReader {

           protected PdsxUserReadOnlyGemsReader(PdsxReadRequest pdsxReadRequest) {
              super(pdsxReadRequest);
           }

           protected ClusterIdEnum getClusterId() {
              return ClusterIdEnum.MARKEPLACE1;
           }

           @Override
           public List<PdsxRecord> readData() {
               List<UserCacheDoImpl> userDos = readUserCacheRecords(req, serverId,startLastModifiedDate, endLastModifiedDate);
               // some code
           }


           private List<UserCacheDoImpl> readUserCacheRecords(PdsxReadRequest req, int serverId, Date startLastModifiedDate, Date endLastModifiedDate) {
              List<UserCacheDoImpl> userDos = new ArrayList<UserCacheDoImpl>();
              BackEndIterator userIter = new BackEndIterator(getClusterId().getId(), serverId, startLastModifiedDate, endLastModifiedDate, READ_BATCH_SIZE);
              //some code
           }


           private PdsxRecord createPdsxRecordFromUserDO(UserCacheDoImpl userCache) {
              //some code
           }

           private void xValidateAttrKey(PdsxAttrKey readAttr) {
              // some code
           }
    }

}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

I need to write another class with the same functionality with all the method names as it is. The only difference is of this method-

```
protected ClusterIdEnum getClusterId() {
    return ClusterIdEnum.MARKEPLACE1;
}
```

It needs to be

```
protected ClusterIdEnum getClusterId() {
    return ClusterIdEnum.MARKEPLACE2;
}
```

So if I need to do it in a very old fashioned way I can just copy paste everything from the first Reader class and make a new Reader2 class by changing the cluster id method. That's all. But that's not a good way.

Can anyone tell me what's the best way to do the same thing without writing any `duplicate code` lot of times.?

I was thinking of something like this by Overriding the `getLcusterId() method` in the Base Class, with code something like this-

```
public class Reader2 extends Reader1 {

    @Override
    public PdsxReader acquireReader(PdsxReadRequest pdsxReadRequest) {
       return new PdsxUserNewReadOnlyGemsReader(pdsxReadRequest);
    }

    protected static class PdsxUserNewReadOnlyGemsReader extends PdsxUserReadOnlyGemsReader {

       protected PdsxUserNewReadOnlyGemsReader(PdsxReadRequest pdsxReadRequest) {
          super(pdsxReadRequest);
       }

       @Override
       protected ClusterIdEnum getClusterId() {
          return ClusterIdEnum.MARKEPLACE2;
       }
    }
}
```

As everything is same in the first class so I don't need to implement anything in my Reader2 class right? It's just that I can override the `getClusterId() method`.

Let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: Yeah you are right. You just need to override `getClusterId()` method, since that is the only functionality that needs to be changed.

Comment: Or add a clusterId field and set it when the Reader object is instanciated? Otherwise it feels like you will need a new class for every other value in ClusterIdEnum

Comment: Thanks Guillaume for the suggestion. Can you provide me an example basis on my code, then I will get a clear picture what you just said right now.

Comment: Why a new class for only a new variable?  Just pass the variable and call based on it.  Seems like lots of the same code repeated.

Answer (score 0):

If it's doable to modify the signature of the `acquireReader` method, you might add a field to your reader class:

```
public class Reader1 extends PdsxAdapterBaseGemsReader {

@Override
public PdsxReader acquireReader(PdsxReadRequest pdsxReadRequest, ClusterIdEnum clusterId) {
   return new PdsxUserReadOnlyGemsReader(pdsxReadRequest, clusterId);
}

protected static class PdsxUserReadOnlyGemsReader extends PdsxAdapterBaseGemsReader.PdsxBaseGemsReader {
       private ClusterIdEnum clusterId;

       protected PdsxUserReadOnlyGemsReader(PdsxReadRequest pdsxReadRequest, ClusterIdEnum clusterId) {
          super(pdsxReadRequest);
          this.clusterId = clusterId;
       }

       protected ClusterIdEnum getClusterId() {
          return clusterId;
       }

       //...
}
```

Alternatively, you can add this in the Reader1 constructor, but it you can pass the clusterId when creating the reader object:

```
public class Reader1 extends PdsxAdapterBaseGemsReader {
       private ClusterIdEnum clusterId;

       public Reader1 (ClusterIdEnum clusterId) {
          this.clusterId = clusterId;
       }

       @Override
       public PdsxReader acquireReader(PdsxReadRequest pdsxReadRequest) {
          return new PdsxUserReadOnlyGemsReader(pdsxReadRequest, clusterId);
       }

protected static class PdsxUserReadOnlyGemsReader extends PdsxAdapterBaseGemsReader.PdsxBaseGemsReader {
       private ClusterIdEnum clusterId;

       protected PdsxUserReadOnlyGemsReader(PdsxReadRequest pdsxReadRequest, ClusterIdEnum clusterId) {
          super(pdsxReadRequest);
          this.clusterId = clusterId;
       }

       protected ClusterIdEnum getClusterId() {
          return clusterId;
       }

       //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Guillaume for the suggestions. Makes sense to me now. It looks like, I cannot modify the signature of `acquireReader` method as it is a part of an `Interface` and several other classes are implementing it currently, so changing the interface will breaks other code as well. So going back to second solution that I posted is the only way I guess by overriding the `getClusterId` method right Guillaume? Let me know if I am missing anything there.